# How to not overwrite colour options array when adding cart item twice with 2 different colors

Tags: php

If I add one item to the cart and select a colour for it then this works fine. However, if I add the same item again but select a different colour it overwrites the initial colour. The quantities are correct (2), but I want to show both colors.

```
    $product_id = $_POST['id'];
    $colour = $_POST['colour'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;

        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array']) || count($_SESSION['cart_array']) < 1) {
            $_SESSION['cart_array'] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $product_id,  "quantity" => 1, "colour" => $colour));


        } else {

            foreach ($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
                $i++;
                while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                    if($key == "item_id" && $value == $product_id) {
                        array_splice($_SESSION['cart_array'], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $product_id, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1, "colour" => $colour)));
                        $wasFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($wasFound == false) {
                array_push($_SESSION['cart_array'], array("item_id" => $product_id, "quantity" => 1, "colour" => $colour));
            }
        }
```

Comment: question: in your system, is it possible to add the same item count = 5 with 3 red and 2 blue?

Comment: How it works is that if add a red item, blue and red again then it shows 3 items in the cart but only lists one item. I would actually like it to show 3 individual items with the different selected colors.

Comment: see my answer below, I change your array format to suit your need so you can have 10 products, 1 red, 6 blue and 3 yellow or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to trasform color variable in your Session cart into array to store multiple variation of color

Somethings like this:

```php
 $product_id = $_POST['id'];
    $colour = $_POST['colour'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;

        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array']) || count($_SESSION['cart_array']) < 1) {
            $_SESSION['cart_array'] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $product_id,  "quantity" => 1, "colour" => $colour));


        } else {

            foreach ($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
                $i++;
                while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                    if($key == "item_id" && $value == $product_id) {
                        array_splice($_SESSION['cart_array'], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $product_id, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1, "colour" => [$each_item['colour'],$colour])));
                        $wasFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($wasFound == false) {
                array_push($_SESSION['cart_array'], array("item_id" => $product_id, "quantity" => 1, "colour" => $colour));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to change your array to something like that:

```
array([item_d] => array('item_id' => [item_d],
                        'count' => [Total_count],
                        'colors'=> array('red' => [red_count],
                                         'blue' => [blue_count]
                                        )
                      );
    );
```

and

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {
     $_SESSION['cart_array'] = array();
  }
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$product_id])) {
  $_SESSION['cart_array'][$product_id] = array("item_id" => $product_id, 'count' => 0, 'colors' =>array());
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$product_id]['colors'][$color])) {
 $_SESSION['cart_array'][$product_id]['colors'][$color] = 1;//1 of color
} else {
 $_SESSION['cart_array'][$product_id]['colors'][$color]++;
}
$_SESSION['cart_array'][$product_id]['count']++;//global count
```